# What does this syntax mean? id<asdfasdf>?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Does anyone know what this syntax do by the MenuDelegate with the  < > brackets??? And why would someone want to complicate a piece of code like this.

```
@protocol MenuDelegate
    - (void)optionSelected:(NSString *)option;
@end

@interface ContentMenu : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *_test;
    id<MenuDelegate> _delegate;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax means that an id variable adopts the protocol called MenuDelegate.

---

The syntax looks strange to me as well, but not as strange as that for calling methods.

Comment: And this is how a class adopts the protocol: `@interface MyClass : NSObject< MenuDelegate > ...` (or whatever its superclass is).

Comment: Why not just put the optionSelected function inside @implementation?

Comment: Because it's a delegate protocol. Other classes may adopt it too, and this pattern simplifies polymorphism.

Comment: @mskw Because it's not `ContentMenu` who implements it. It is an object of unknown type passed to the class as `_delegate` that has that implementation. Declaring `id<MenuDelegate>` says that we don't care what is the actual type of the object, as long as we can be assured of the possibility to call its `optionSelected:` method. By the way, it is a good idea to declare your delegates `__weak` under ARC to avoid retain cycles.

Answer (score 0):

That's protocol. Protocol in Objective-C is interface declaration. It allows you to specify a certain set of methods that you expect in the delegate, without enforcing the type of the object passed in.

`id<MenuDelegate>` means any class that implements the `MenuDelegate` protocol. It guarantees that you can call the functions specified in `MenuDelegate` protocol, without bothering about the real type of the object.

Comment: Why do this?  I can easily remove the protocol and just put the optionSelected function inside @implementation, and I can get the same result.

Comment: It's a way to enforce the delegate to implement certain function - and the compiler will generate warning if the class doesn't implement the function in the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Just as static typing permits the compiler to test for a type based on the class hierarchy, this syntax permits the compiler to test for a type based on conformance to a protocol.For more information read [The Objective-C 2.0 Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

See what Apple documents say about protocol

> If you know the class of an object, you can look at its **interface
>   declaration** (and the interface declarations of the classes it inherits
>   from) to find what messages it responds to. **These declarations
>   advertise the messages it can receive. Protocols provide a way for it
>   to also advertise the messages it sends**.
>
> Communication works both ways; objects send messages as well as
>   receive them. For example, an object might delegate responsibility for
>   a certain operation to another object, or it may on occasion simply
>   need to ask another object for information. In some cases, an object
>   might be willing to notify other objects of its actions so that they
>   can take whatever collateral measures might be required.
>
> If you develop the class of the sender and the class of the receiver
>   as part of the same project (or if someone else has supplied you with
>   the receiver and its interface file), this communication is easily
>   coordinated. The sender simply imports the interface file of the
>   receiver. The imported file declares the method selectors the sender
>   uses in the messages it sends.

So this is the answer of your question

```
Why not just put the optionSelected function inside @implementation?
```

Comment: to see the whole document just refer the link provided by @Prasad G in below answer